# How to put an image inside GoogleMaps api snippet

Tags: java, android, image, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to insert a snippet with an image inside, whenever someone will click the marker they will see a bitmap image inside the marker description (snippet).

```
  mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(SYDNEY)
            .title("test")
            .snippet(IMAGE HERE)
            .icon();
```

I have an URL with a image how do i do it?

Comment: can you add some example image how that should look like?

Comment: @jagapathi just an image inside the snippet, like that: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pnpCR7AmHhQ/UPi07Uttk8I/AAAAAAAAG78/1Pl2txukbTs/s400/AndroidMapV2_InfoContents.png but inside the snippet and not in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for image loading

**This is java code for inflating custom info window**

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
            v[0] = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_info_design, null);
            if (marker != null) {

                final ImageView logo=(ImageView)v[0].findViewById(R.id.logo);




                t1=new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                };
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(b1.get(Integer.parseInt(marker.getSnippet()))).error(R.drawable.logo_icon)
                        .into(logo,new MarkerCallback(marker));

            }
            return (v[0]);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {


            return null;
        }
    });
```

**Layout XML file (R.layout.custom_marker_maps)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/comment_icon"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Add this code for callback (to solve Picasso bug)**

```
static class MarkerCallback implements Callback {
    Marker marker=null;

    MarkerCallback(Marker marker) {
        this.marker=marker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error loading thumbnail!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you but It appears that you just changed the marker's icon I asked about the little window (Info Window) after you click the marker, how to load an image to there?

Comment: you need to make custom info window (editing my answer)

Comment: how do I do it? how do I make it appear when you press a marker?

Comment: In the first code box where is b1 comes from?? i get many errors from the first box code... (i implemented the picasso)

Comment: @drdisrespect arraylist of images (part of my code)

Comment: @drdisrespect can you explain

Comment: In which function did you put the first box code in? (OnCreate or onMapReady) or just inside the class?

Comment: i call a function when i am adding marker (this code is in same function)

Comment: Thank's i did it!

Answer (score 0):

```
fromAsset(String assetName) – Loading from assets folder
fromBitmap (Bitmap image) – Loading bitmap image
fromFile (String path) – Loading from file
fromResource (int resourceId) – Loading from drawable resource

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

// Changing marker icon
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon)));

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: this is how to change the icon of the marker, I asked how to put an image from URL to the markers snippet.

Comment: URL url = new URL("http://imageURL");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
googleMap.addMarker(bmp);

Comment: Please refer this site 'http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html'